# Keycloak: how to add/update user with roles programmatically?

Tags: java, keycloak

I am trying to update a user, with admin role, for the realm using admin console, but it's not working.

My code:

```
UserResource use = userResources.get(search.get(0).getId());
use.resetPassword(credentials);

user=use.toRepresentation();
List<String> roles=new ArrayList<String>();
roles.add("realm-admin");
Map<String,List<String>> m= new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

m.put("realm-management",roles);
user.setClientRoles(m);
use.update(user);
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

```
UserResource use = userResources.get(idUser);

use.roles().clientLevel(id).add(use.roles().clientLevel( 
id).listAvailable());
```

This is the solution I found the id is the id of the client and not the client_id.